# APT reporting disk full but disk isn't full!

Tags: package-management

Usually I am able to google my way out of problems with apt but this one has me stumped.  It's obviously complaining about lacking disk space but it's reporting that it can't even create a directory on sda1?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my output from what I tried.

```
duncan@BEDROOM:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /dev
tmpfs           328M  1.4M  326M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        14G  9.8G  3.1G  76% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.6G   13M  1.6G   1% /run/shm
none            100M  8.0K  100M   1% /run/user



duncan@BEDROOM:~$ sudo apt-get clean


duncan@BEDROOM:~$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

duncan@BEDROOM:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed
linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 688 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic i386 3.13.0-100.147 [688 kB]
Fetched 688 kB in 1s (433 kB/s)                           
(Reading database ... 422618 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic_3.13.0-100.147_i386.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic (3.13.0-100.147) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic_3.13.0-100.147_i386.deb (--unpack):
unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic/include/config/sensors/g762.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic/include/config/sensors/g762.h'): No space left on device
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic_3.13.0-100.147_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and in case it matters:

```
duncan@BEDROOM:~$ uname -a
Linux BEDROOM 3.13.0-100-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 16:49:53 UTC 2016 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You didn't give us the details about what you were trying to do, and when/what error messages you received. Cheers, Al

Comment: Could you also [edit] in the output of `df -i`.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the disk was kinda full.  I was close to exhausting inodes.

```
root@BEDROOM:~# df -i

Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           207347    498 206849    1% /dev
tmpfs          214299    525 213774    1% /run
/dev/sda1      909312 906196   3116  100% /
none           214299      2 214297    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           214299      3 214296    1% /run/lock
none           214299    133 214166    1% /run/shm
none           214299     10 214289    1% /run/user
```

Have to figure out what is using up so many now.

Edit:  Ironically it was the old linux header files taking up a lot of inodes.  So I deleted the oldest 2 versions manually from /usr/src which freed enough up to do your script which in turn freed up even more.

After running apt-get purge $OLDCONF from kyodake's script:

```
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      909312 889004  20308   98% /
```

After running apt-get purge $OLDKERNELS

```
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      909312 644406 264906   71% /
```

and I now have another 4gb free

Thanks Kyodake!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)
apt-get clean
apt-get purge $OLDCONF
apt-get purge $OLDKERNELS
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get dist-upgrade
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get clean
```

Comment: Not to sound ungrateful but I am not going to do that right away until I know what it is actually going to do.

Comment: @kyodake yes... your answer requires a **lot** of explanation. Cheers, Al

Comment: I think I get what you have suggested.  You are itemising all the packages that have been removed but still have config files by stripping out unnecessary text from dpkg output.  I think you also have IDed the kernel revision and removed any text from it also.  You have then took the list of packages and matched them back up with their revisions by running dpkg and some awk wizardry which produces a list of packages to be purged completely.  Oh and you emptied the trash and tidied up.

Comment: I ran it line by line because I wasn't convinced it would actually help with this problem.     After running the first purge I got:The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies.